# Rails 4 app links failing to generate correct URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c9.io

I have a rails 4 app under development in c9 cloud IDE and I have a view file that displays entries from different models.
 My issue is certain links in the file fails when clicked while other links on the same page seems working. I have this code in my app view to generate links

```
<%= link_to '確認ここへ', "/#{applist.controller_name.strip}/#{applist.wfs_id}/edit" %>
```

for most of the  models it generates correct URL like ide.c9.io/dname/arubaito_boshu/491/edit while certain models fails like https://funin_teate_shikyu/new/518/edit
Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is really the anti pattern of rails links.
To generate links in rails please use the according `..._path` method.

You can see your routes with the following command:

```
$ bin/rake routes
```

Which would give you some output like this:

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
```

From there you can take your prefix for the `path` method.

With the routes above it's quite simple:

```
<%= link_to "New User", new_user_path %>
```

Which will generate this:

```
<a href="/users/new">New User</a>
```

If you have dynamic routes you can define a route like this.

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/something/:id' => 'something#show', as: :something
end
```

then in your controller:

```
# app/controllers/something_controller.rb
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
  def show
    puts params[:id]
  end 
end
```

Now if you visit `/something/this-is-awesome`, you can access the passed value (which in this case is: this-is-awesome) by using: params[:id] (see controller code)

Comment: The entries r displayed dynamically in the page based on many scenarios, so I can't hard code the resource path the way u mentioned :(

Comment: you sure can. Look at his examples, `:id` for example is a variable. You can just define the routes with variables in your routes file and call the paths lile: `my_magic_path(:variable_1, :some_other_attribute)